# Custom method for update query with spring data MongoRepository

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, mongorepository

I am using  org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository. I have written some custom method like below,

```
public interface DocRepository extends MongoRepository<Doc, String> {
     Doc findByDocIdAndAssignmentId(final String docId, final String assignemtId);
}
```

How can I write a custom method which update all entries when meeting a criteria.

For example set document tilte field to "abc" if assignment id is "xyz"?

Answer (score 9):

1) You need to create inteface e.g CustomDocRepository and add this interfaces as Base for your DocRepository:

```
public interface DocRepository extends MongoRepository<Doc, String>, CustomDocRepository {

    void updateDocumentTitle(String id, String title);

}
```

2) You need to add implementation for the DocRepository:

```
@Repository
public class CustomDocRepositoryImpl implements DocRepository {
  @Autowired
  private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;


@Override
public void updateDocumentTitle(String id, String title) {
    Query query = new Query().addCriteria(where("_id").is(id));

    Update update = new Update();
    update.set("title", title);
    mongoTemplate.update(Doc.class).matching(query).apply(update).first();
}
}
```

That is all you need to do

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/index.html#repositories.single-repository-behavior 9.6. Custom Implementations for Spring Data Repositories

Comment: No possible way to do it by writing a query in a `@Query` annotated method in repository?

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have an `autowired` attribute `mongoTemplate` in your `service` class. Add the below code to update the document.

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("assignmentId").is("xyz"))
Update update = new Update();
update.set("title", "abc");
mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, Doc.class);
```

You dont need to have `findByDocIdAndAssignmentId` for the update purpose.

Comment: Actually i dont have mongoTemplate. I am looking custom method for update operation with out using mongoTemplate

Comment: Did you get the answer?

Answer (score -3):

I found com.mongodb.MongoClient to achieve the above