# Custom @Query annotated method for update query with spring data MongoRepository

Tags: java, spring-boot

I've read the question [Custom method for update query with spring data MongoRepository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020046/custom-method-for-update-query-with-spring-data-mongorepository) and my result would be the very same that it is in que previously mentioned question, the only difference would be that I want to do it by using a `@Query` annotated method. Is it possible? If so, how?

I have a entity and I what to update all documents with a value if a determined criteria has been match.

My entity:

```
@Document("accrual")
public class Accrual extends AbstractEntity {

    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1175443967269096002L;

    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private Long numericUserId;
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private Long orderIdentifier;
    private boolean error;

    // sets, gets, equals, hashCode and toString methods
}
```

I would like to update the boolean error in every document found by searching for them using a list of `Long`s matching `orderIdentifier` attribute.

If it was in a relational database I would have a method like:

```
@Query(value = "update accrual set error = 0 where order_identifier in :list", nativeQuery = true)
updateErrorByOrderIdentifier(@Param("list") List<Long> orderIdentifiers)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `@Query` annotation for filtering documents to be updated and `@Update` for providing actual update query.

```
@Query("{ 'orderIdentifier' : { '$in': ?0 } }")
@Update("{ '$set' : { 'error' : 'false' } }")
void updateAllByOrderIdentifier(List<Long> orderIdentifiers);
```

More details can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries.update)

Comment: Is it possible to return the updated elements?

Comment: Not sure, because MongoDB after update return only the count of updated elements.

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'Update'